# There's a question stuck on the 'deleted' list

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

In the 10K tools for stackoverflow, there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809945/malware-technical-anlaysis-closed) that was migrated. Yet, it sits there, using a space, without a delete link, on the list of things with pending delete votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That single delete vote was cast a few days after the question was initially closed as ["off-topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2809945/revisions).  You are correct that the vote will hang around without moderator intervention.

What should have occurred is that **upon question reopening, pending delete votes are removed** - we'll change reopening to work this way.

Comment: I've removed that delete vote now.

Answer (score -1):

It's on the list of things with pending delete votes because it has a pending delete vote. How is this a bug?

Comment: It doesn't show me a pending delete vote. How, anyway, can something already migrated to another site have a pending delete vote?

Comment: it's a bug to show it in the list, suggesting that it can be voted on.  This is a problem only because there is a hard limit of 15 questions that ever show up in this list -- so this question will be using up a slot until it finally expires in 30 days.