# Why does this question show an inconsistent number of undelete votes?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, 10k-tools, vote-to-undelete

I was looking in the delete tab, and saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44900) showing 1 undelete vote (30 day view), but the question shows 2 undelete votes in the question itself. It doesn't appear that the post was undeleted by anyone previously.

If there is an undelete vote older than 30 days, then there really ought to be a "max" or "all" view in the delete tab so we can see how many votes there actually are on those questions.

Do delete/undelete votes decay like close votes and flags do? (I couldn't find this in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222), so that should be updated regardless.)

Is this somehow related to [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50173/theres-a-question-stuck-on-the-deleted-list)?

---

I'm not sure if this is a bug report, or a support question, or a feature request... I'll edit when I get more information from the answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the post in question was undeleted, then promptly redeleted, which destroyed the situation.

I suspect that delete votes do not decay and it was simply a matter of the first vote being older than 30 days.

---

I think a "max" view (or something longer than 30 days, say 90 days) in the 10k tools is still a good idea, though that should be requested in a separate question.