# Please clear delete votes from locked question

Tags: support, specific-question, 10k-tools

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848368/why-do-some-languages-not-use-semicolons-and-braces-closed) is locked with pending deletes, so it just sits there eating a slot on the pending delete list. Can someone flush the delete votes?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50173/theres-a-question-stuck-on-the-deleted-list

Answer (score 3):

And please filter out all locked questions from the close/delete tabs of the 10k tools, while you're at it.